# Magento2.4 auto ceate layout xml file

Tags: layout

In the Magento2.4 community website, I need to define a CMS page layout every time I do a lot of active pages. Is there a way to automatically create an XML layout file based on the URL of my site, so that every time the site's promoters do an event, they don't need a technician to write code for the layout file